# Why not to maximize Sharpe Ratio directly when computing optimal allocation of an order?

Tags: risk-management, sharpe-ratio, order-execution, transaction-costs

I was reading the following paper of Engle about balancing transaction costs performance and risk:
https://www.nber.org/papers/w12165.pdf

He deals with finding the optimal placement of the child orders, and he does so maximizing a term akin to
$$\max_{child \, order \, placement} (\mathbb{E}[Return - Transaction Costs] - Var(Return - Transaction Costs))$$.

He goes on stating that, from this, we can evaluate the effectiveness of our placement strategy by evaluating the Adjusted Sharpe Ratio:

$$\frac{\mathbb{E}[Return - Transaction Costs] - R_f}{\sqrt{Var(Return - Transaction Costs)}}.$$

My question is: **if the metric used to evaluate the execution strategy is the Sharpe, why not maximize that in the first place?** It seems to me that the two maximization problems in general lead to different results.

Comment: Hi: You can try to maximize the sharpe ratio and involve transaction cost in that optimization.  ( see Perold, for example but I forget the year and title of paper ). I didn't read the Engle paper but  It sounds like he's trying do some kind of optimization after the order amounts are known. But,  if the results have already been optimized as you describe (using your approach of involving the transaction cost in the optimization ) , then you are correct that what he's doing would be redundant.